# How to extend the URLPopover render settings for the paragraph Gutenberg block?

Tags: block-editor

Add this moment when you enter an URL in a Paragraph-block there is only one setting: Open in New Tab. I like to be able to add settings such as Link Style. That adds a class to a link.

Comment: This will almost certainly require a good amount of javascript knowledge to do, and there is no guarantee it can actually be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It cannot be done, no API currently exists to add what you want to add.**

If we look at the component that implements this:

https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/5b01c97c6943890abb44b2154392ffcccef87b3e/packages/format-library/src/link/inline.js#L197

The `InlineLinkUI` wraps a component that wraps the `URLPopover` component, and places a child component inside it which is how the new window checkbox is added. No slots are present or hooks for intercepting this.

Judging from what you want to do, I don't think this is the intended path forward. Instead, build a block, or a new inline block. You can also open an issue on the Gutenberg GitHub requesting the feature

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you elaborate more on what you mean with a new Inline Block? Do you mean a block with a display:inline-block style?

Comment: No, there's a type of block that appears inline in a paragraph block, but it's not mentioned often, here's the PR that first introduced the feature https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/pull/6959

Comment: More about Format API: https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/tutorials/format-api/